# SQL Displaying duplicate values with same parent ID on next Column

Tags: sql-server

I've been searching and trying different queries in SQL Server 2008 R2 but unable to get the results I'm looking for.  Here's my question on a query.  On the same table I have the following

```
ObjectID    ParentID    FlowerID
1           5           100
2           1           100
3           1           105
4           5           103
```

I'm trying to get parentID that has multiple FlowerID to display on the next column so it will look something like this.

```
ParentID    FlowerID1    FlowerID2
5           100          103
1           100          105
```

Any one can point me towards the correction and I might be able to figure out the rest.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
declare @data as table(ObjectID  int,ParentID int,FlowerID int)
insert into @data values(1 ,5, 100)
insert into @data values(2 ,1, 100 )
insert into @data values(3 ,1, 105)
insert into @data values(4, 5, 103)
select d1.ParentID,stuff((select ' '+ convert(varchar,d2.FlowerID) from @data d2 where d2.ParentID = d1.ParentID for xml path('')),1,1,'') from @data d1 group by d1.ParentID having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is typically accomplished using `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT ParentID, [FlowerID1], [FlowerID2] 
FROM 
   (SELECT ParentID, FlowerID, 
           'FlowerID' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID ORDER BY FlowerID) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS FlowerLabel
    FROM mytable) AS src
PIVOT
(  
   MAX(FlowerID)     
   FOR FlowerLabel IN ([FlowerID1], [FlowerID2] )
) pvt
```

**Output:**

```
ParentID    FlowerID1   FlowerID2
-----------------------------------
1           100         105
5           100         103
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5557/1)